# Laravel SESSION DRIVER file and database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller

I always encounter this error in my laravel apps.It seems like my app is looking for SESSION table. But my session driver is file.

> Error Code : 942 Error Message : ORA-00942: table or view does not exist Position : 29 Statement : 
>       select * from (select * from "SESSIONS" where "ID" = :p0) where rownum = 1 Bindings : [ 
>       6FIQK2ZudGtfcRksXb0E9lIJtcq3OcNIsjSWNAU1] (SQL: select * from (select * from "SESSIONS" where "ID" = 
>       6FIQK2ZudGtfcRksXb0E9lIJtcq3OcNIsjSWNAU1) where rownum = 1)

This is the .env configuration

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Same with the session.php

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

How to remove this error. Which php file should i edit.

Comment: Surely if the SESSION_DRIVER is `file` then it in NOT being stored on a database table it is being stored in a file

Comment: did you try to clear your config cache?

Comment: @Giacimo M yes tried it too many times.

Answer (score 0):

I would try isolating the problem by setting mailtrap SMTP settings and test if emails arrive there. If so, problem is with your SMTP settings. Otherwise, there is something wrong in your code. Please share a peace of code where we can see how you are sending the email.

Here is a guide on setting mailtrap SMTP settings in laravel: https://medium.com/@christianjombo/setting-up-mailtrap-for-laravel-development-313133bb800c